# The requested URL /services was not found on this server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a LAMP environment. Running Ubuntu 14.04

I have installed and configured everything correctly (or at least I think so) but only the homepage of my website loads.

My domain is www.codeclimb.com but if you navigate to any other pages I get this error

```
The requested URL /services was not found on this server.
```

Here is my vhost setting for apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


ServerAdmin chris@codeclimb.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/codeclimb.com/public_html

    ServerName codeclimb.com
    ServerAlias www.codeclimb.com

</VirtualHost>
```

What can possibly be the problem? I can log into my wordpress admin panel but no content loads. I can only see the sidebar with links to "dashboard, posts, settings, ect..." but will not display content on the right side of the page.

Comment: is your .htaccess file fine?

Comment: also try this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9zESEfNzSQ#t=165

Comment: I upload the same .htaccess file from my server before. What should I look out for? @random21

Comment: Is there an `Alias` for `/services` that you may have forgotten to include in the config?

Comment: Is there any trace in the error and access log what the server tries the URL to resolve to?